# How can we initialize a webdriver instance without declaring it static and use the same instance in all pageObjects classe

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, constructor, pageobjects

```
public class Base
{

    public WebDriver driver;

    public void initializeDriver()
    {
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    }
}

public class Page extends Base
{

    Page(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver=driver;
    }

    @Test
    public void testPage() 
    {
       driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
    }
}
```

**In Page Class**

Why we need the constructor in each page class that extends the base class. What is the purpose of this constructor and how it works.
I am confused with the use of constructor in page class.Please help me to understand its working here.Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is your question? the title or the one in the text? if both of them you should split it to two separate questions, and if only one of them edit this question accordingly.

Comment: Actually , i am confused that how the constructor  used in each page class is used to initialize the WebDriver instance (without declaring it static )in Base class. Can you please help me to understand this way for initializing the WebDriver instance

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not totally clear because in title you ask something else than in the content of question but I will try to answer:

I think you have two options how to initialize WebDriver without using static driver.

**First option:** you will not use constructor but you will initialize web driver ucalling setUp() method everytime you run a test.

```
public class Base {
   protected WebDriver driver;

   @BeforeClass
   public void setUp() {
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver.linux");
       driver = new ChromeDriver();
   }
   @AfterClass
   public void tearDown() {
       driver.quit();
   }
}


public class Page extends Base {
    @Test
    public void testPage() {
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/");
    }
}
```

**Second option:** You will use constructor in Page Class to initialize web driver in Base class. Here you could always pass same instance of webdriver. (UPDATE this option is not good)

```
public class PageClass{
   public PageClass(WebDriver driver){
       this.driver = driver;
   }

   public void testPage() {
       driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/");
   }
}
public class MainTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver.linux");
       WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
       PageClass pageClassTest = new PageClass(driver);
       pageClassTest.testPage();
      }
}
```

maybe clarifying your question would help

UPDATE second option is wrong if you use junit or ngtest you should use no-arg constructor and initialize driver in @BeforeClass method. When you really insist on using driver constructor you have to create your own main method where you will run your code but I suppose you will use the advantage of unit test frameworks.

Also if you want to share one instance of webdriver declare it static. You will just read from this parameter. So I don't see problem when you want to run tests in parallel. Or if there is some p

Comment: SteveSk - Thank you very much for quick reply. currently ,i am using the first option for initializing the webdriver and it work fine.But  why some blog suggest to use second option i.e using constructor. is there any other advantage we get using the constructor way.First option is simple and works fine ,then why should we go for the second option?Thanks..

Comment: **org.testng.TestNGException: 
Can't invoke public void Page.testPage(): either make it static or add a no-args constructor to your class**  -Getting this error when initializing the driver using second option.

Comment: I think adding no-args constructor to Base class should solve the problem?

Comment: Even if i add the constructor to base class, then how the statement              ' driver = new FirefoxDriver(); ' will get executed in base class. If this code is not executed then running the test method will throw null Poointer exception. can you please provide me a working code where webdriver  initialized in base class and same instance is passed in all page class using constructor.?

Comment: ok I look to the issue more and update my answer optio nwith the constructor is wrong using frameworks like junit and testng...I think you should use first option with or without static webdriver

Answer (score 0):

You do not need constructors in your Page classes. Furthermore, you can make all its methods static and see how it helps reduce many lines of code.

We can easily get the idea of Page object model by looking at the tests first. Here is an example test case:

- go to Login page
- enter username, password and click [Submit] button
- wait for the Home page to load and verify something there, like a user display name and a menu [Logout] is present

You can write many other cases, such as submit an invalid username/password. So you don't want to repeat the code to find elements, type into or click it. Instead, write methods in a Login page class. This class holds all the element locators and provides methods to interact with them.

Here I write all-static Page classes:

```
public class TestBase {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeMethod
    public void init() {
        //create the driver here
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void teardown() {
        //quit the driver here
    }
    public static pause(int millis) {
        //
    }
}
public class LoginPage extends TestBase {
    static By txtUsername = By.xpath("//form//input[@name='username']");
    public static fillUsername(String username) {
        WebElement e = driver.findElement(txtUsername);
        e.clear();
        e.sendKeys(username);
    }
    //other elements...
}
public class Home extends TestBase {
    // locators
    // methods to click, read data, test element presence, ...
}
public class Test1 extends TestBase {
    @Test
    public void testValidLogin() {
        driver.get("http://example.com");
        pause(5000);
        Login.fillUsername("user1");
        Login.fillPassword("secret");
        Login.clickSubmit();
        pause(5000);
        Home.testLogoutBtnPresent();
    }
}
```

In above code, driver is static and is created in @BeforeMethod. You might, but rarely, need to create different driver instances. As long as my tests do not require concurrent sessions, I will use a static driver. I personally find having to create new instances of Page will lead to much longer test methods and raise significant amount of think time (when to create, how I name the instance, whether I can reuse an instance).

Comment: Thanks..i actually need to execute my testcases parallely.